# Customize NodeJS Deployment Process on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am building NodeJS application that uses MongoDB and deploy to Heroku.
I'm using [east migration library](https://github.com/okv/east-mongo) and I want to run the migration command during the deployment process.

How can I do that?

Should I fork the buildpack or is there easier way?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way.

When your application is being deployed to Heroku, Heroku is executing `npm install --production` to install all dependencies. Once completed, the `postinstall` script is executed. You can define a `postinstall` script in your `package.json` file. In this script, you can run your migrations.

The below is a snippet I'm using in my [Node on Fire](http://nodeonfire.org/)-based projects. This will execute `grunt build` and `grunt release` when deployed to Heroku (or `npm install` is otherwise executed).

```
{
  ..

  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt build && ./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt release"
  },

  ..
}
```

In your case, create a `postinstall` with the following value `./node_modules/east/bin/east migrate`. This should execute your migrations on Heroku. You should make sure `east` is listed in `dependencies` and not `devDependencies` as Heroku is not installing `devDependencies`. You can also not use any global dependencies in the `postinstall` script, as your dependencies are never installed globally on Heroku (with the default buildpack that is).